# Apple store submission guidelines questions

Tags: ios, app-store

I am now preparing to submit a new app to the Apple iTunes store, and I have a question with regard to the guidelines, which rose when I read through the guidelines.

1. What are the things I need to submit for an app review?
2. If my app is rejected, on what grounds can I exactly appeal?
3. Is it possible to resubmit an app for review, after taking into consideration the possible points for rejection have been corrected, and if so, what is the exact procedure?
4. What is the minimum time period that will be taken for a review, the first time and for an update? (I read that review can be expedited under certain grounds, but I am referring here to the normal update process)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give you as much information as I can, but you should search more on the Internet or SO, because I'm sure there are plenty of answers.

Anyway, this is a possible duplicate, but here are some informations :

First of all, your questions are too broad. What do you mean? You want to know the process?

In order to submit an App to the AppleStore, you need **Production Certificate**.

You can check if everything is setup properly by checking your signing options :

- Open xCode, click on your target, general tab, Signing part.
- Here is the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html).
- You can also check everything on the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/).

You have to Archive your App, **xCode** - **Product** - **Archive**.
Then you can export it with the Organizer.
When you have your .ipa file, you can upload it for submission with Application Loader **Xcode** - **Open Developer Tool** - **Application Loader**.

The process might be painful the first time, but after two or three Release, you will handle it easily.

Your App might be rejected for plenty of reasons, anyway Apple will send you an email containing the reason if your App is rejected.

The delay may vary, sometimes it took 2 or 3 days, sometimes 10+.

When your App is finally accepted, log in on [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), and you will find the "+ Version" option on the left.

It will enables you to deploy the build you want on the AppStore.

Hope it will help, don't hesitate to search on the Internet, or look documentations, tutorial.

Good luck for your release.

Comment: Hi @Murloc, and thank you for answering my question. Your answer answered most of my questions.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)